# Get child element without id or class attributes with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following HTML code :

```
<div id="someId">
  <div ng-transclude>
  </div>
</div>
```

Really simple I am getting the div element which has ID attribute using the following function :

```
var getElementById = function (id) {
    return angular.element("#" + id);
};
```

Where in this example case the ID is 'someId'. My goal is to get the div inside the one I just got. So I want to return the div with ng-transclude attribute. I believe that this will happen by getting an element by attribute name or something.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I can't put any other attributes in the div I wanted(like id) because in the real life it is far more complecated and the code is auto-generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you

```
 var getElementByAttribute = function (attribute) {
        return angular.element(document).find('[' + attribute + ']');
 };

 var el = getElementByAttribute('ng-transclude')
```

Comment: Great! Works just fine and it is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that will be the Angular way, but you can use native properties of the HTML element. Something like this:

```
var getElementById = function (id) {
    return angular.element("#" + id);
};

var childDivWithTransclude = getElementById('someId').children[0];
```